# Show that if S = {b1,b2,...,bk} in any generating set for V, then the pivot columns of the matrix ...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. According to the extension theorem, a linearly independent subset $L = \{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}$ of $V$ is contained in a basis for $V$.
Show that if $S = \{b_1,b_2,...,b_k\}$ in any generating set for $V$, then the pivot columns of the matrix [$u_1,u_2,...,u_k,b_1,b_2,...,b_k$] form a basis for $V$ that contains $L$.

I am having a big troubles with solving this one.
Spent hours on it but cannot get to a proof of this. Anyone who got a hint to share? Will be deeply appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to the one who edited it. Really dunno how to make it so neat. Really thank u.

Comment: I solved it. Will post the solution when I get my homework back.